# Javascript library for Pearson and/or Spearman correlations

Tags: javascript, statistics, correlation

Is there a Javascript library available for doing [Spearman and/or Pearson](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8071/how-to-choose-between-pearson-and-spearman-correlation/8077#8077) correlations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is this

http://stevegardner.net/2012/06/11/javascript-code-to-calculate-the-pearson-correlation-coefficient/

apart from that you could try:

http://www.jstat.org/download

alternatively if neither of those fit the bill and you don't want to write one yourself you can always use:

http://www.rforge.net/Rserve/

with

http://www.gardenersown.co.uk/education/lectures/r/correl.htm

to do it.

Comment: Does jStat do pearson or spearman? I only see a "correlation coefficient" mentioned in the docs, but not pearson specifically.

Comment: @trusktr It looks like you're right, sorry, I thought it did.

Comment: Correlation coefficient is usually the Pearson, isn't it? and Spearman is nothing less than a Pearson on the ranks of your data, right?

Answer (score 9):

So here's my two pennies worth on the matter - Pearson correlation:

```js
const pcorr = (x, y) => {
  let sumX = 0,
    sumY = 0,
    sumXY = 0,
    sumX2 = 0,
    sumY2 = 0;
  const minLength = x.length = y.length = Math.min(x.length, y.length),
    reduce = (xi, idx) => {
      const yi = y[idx];
      sumX += xi;
      sumY += yi;
      sumXY += xi * yi;
      sumX2 += xi * xi;
      sumY2 += yi * yi;
    }
  x.forEach(reduce);
  return (minLength * sumXY - sumX * sumY) / Math.sqrt((minLength * sumX2 - sumX * sumX) * (minLength * sumY2 - sumY * sumY));
};
let arrX = [20, 54, 54, 65, 45];
let arrY = [22, 11, 21, 34, 87];
let R = pcorr(arrX, arrY);
console.log('arrX', arrX, 'arrY', arrY, 'R', R);
```

Answer (score 3):

I used the Spearson project [here](https://github.com/agrueneberg/Spearson) on Github. I've tested it for Spearman correlation and it gives accurate values for that.

I just downloaded the `spearson.js` file in the `/lib` folder of the repo. Here's how to use it in the browser:

`<script src="spearson.js"></script>`

```
<script>
    var x = [3, 4, 5];
    var y = [.1, .2, .3];
    var corr = spearson.correlation.spearman(x, y);
</script>
```

Similarly, you can use the `correlation.pearson` for the Pearson correlation.

Answer (score 2):

After many years since initial question was asked I recommend this great library which is straightforward though still well documented:
**[statistics.js](https://thisancog.github.io/statistics.js/index.html)**

Among many other methods it has [correlationCoefficient()](https://thisancog.github.io/statistics.js/inc/correlation.html) which computes **Pearson’s correlation coefficient** of two variables and [spearmansRho()](https://thisancog.github.io/statistics.js/inc/correlation.html#spearmansrho) which does **Spearman’s rank correlation coefficient**.

Comment: Seems to be a rich library but doesn't have declarations for typescript

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function spearmanCorrelation(multiList, p1, p2){
    N=multiList[p1].length;
    order=[];
    sum=0;

    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        order.push([multiList[p1][i], multiList[p2][i]]);
    }

    order.sort(function(a,b){
        return a[0]-b[0]
    });

    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        order[i].push(i+1);
    }

    order.sort(function(a,b){
        return a[1]-b[1]
    });

    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        order[i].push(i+1);
    }
    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        sum+=Math.pow((order[i][2])-(order[i][3]), 2);

    }

    r=1-(6*sum/(N*(N*N-1)));

    return r;
}
```